# How to replace line that starts with certain string in Tcl ? Is it wrong to use bash inside Tcl?

Tags: bash, replace, sed, tcl

I am writing Tcl script and one part of it envolves replacing the first occurrence of a line containing some string pattern with another line. I did it using sed as a bash command inside Tcl as follows :

```
exec bash -c {sed 0,/Apple/{s/Apple/Banana/ File}
```

My question is is there a direct way to do this using Tcl command, also is it wrong or not recommended  to use a lot of Bash commands inside Tcl ?

Thanks

Comment: look for examples of the `sub` function in the tcl manuals. There is very little that you can't do in tcl, calling bash or any shell should not be needed, except in unusual cases. Good luck.

Comment: In general, you want to avoid inter-mixing languages as much as possible.  If you find yourself using lots of Bash inside your Tcl code, that might be a hint that your task is better suited for a Bash script than a Tcl script.  You can use Tcl to do almost anything that you can do in Bash, though, so try to stick to Tcl.

Answer (score 5):

There is a `regsub` command for exactly this:

```
regsub -- {Apple} $line Banana line
```

Here's [the official documentation.](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm)

And if you need help reading the first line of a file, [this page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/367) may help.

Comment: Actually, the _official_ HTML documentation is on www.tcl.tk, and that's built using the official tooling from the official documentation sources (in nroff, in all Tcl source distributions).

Comment: Also note that for files that fit nicely in memory, say up to a million lines or so, you can read it all in at once into a single string and use `regsub` (maybe in line-anchored mode) on it all at once.

Comment: @DonalFellows - Oops, I'm not sure why my Google search turned that one up first. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of `[string]` commands:

```
proc replaceFirst {text find replace} {
    set idx [string first $find $text]
    if {$idx == -1} {return $text}     ;# search string not found in text
    set end [expr {$idx + [string length $find] - 1}]
    string replace $text $idx $end $replace
}

replaceFirst "I hear Apple makes many popular Apple products." Apple Banana
# => I hear Banana makes many popular Apple products.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace strings in a block of text:

```
set text [string map {Apple Banana} $text]
```

If you want to update strings in a file, the `fileutil` package has just the ticket: `fileutil::updateInPlace`:

```
package require fileutil
proc processLine {line} { return [string map {Apple Banana} $line] }
fileutil::updateInPlace file.txt processLine
```

Note that the `string map` command can replace many strings at once:

```
string map {Apple Banana Monkey Ape Coke Pepsi} $text
```

#### Update

It turns out that string map will replace all instances Apple, which is not what Ahmed wanted (thanks to Glenn for pointing that out). That we should go with acheong87's regsub solution:

```
package require fileutil
proc processLine {line} { return [regsub -- {Apple} $line "Banana"] }
fileutil::updateInPlace file.txt processLine
```

Comment: While a good answer, the question did ask about replacing only the first instance of Apple with Banana -- `string map` will replace all.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. I missed that. In that case, we should go with the regsub solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, reaching out for `sed` here appears to be neat (due to `sed`'s declarative expressiveness) but redundant and making maintenance of your program more difficult as adding each "moving part" raises the complexity.

Basically, the steps you need to follow to reimplement your snippet in plain Tcl are:

1. Open the source file.
2. Repeatedly call `gets` on the file's channel to read data from it line by line.
3. Perform a properly constructed call to `regsub` on each line, which would try to replace "Apple" with "Banana".
4. As soon as the call to `regsub` returned 1 or more meaning the string matched your regex, quit the file reading loop.

The rest of implementaton depends on what you're doing with your data.

Second, even if you opt to execute `sed` from your Tcl script, you surely do not need to involve the shell here as the Tcl's `exec` command is able to cope with command pipelines and stream redirections by itself.

Another non-obvious problem with your current approach is that inlining one script (for `sed`) in another script (for shell) might easily create escaping nightmares: try to think what happens if either your source pattern or your replacement pattern might be arbitrary data which can contain whitespace characters as well as single and double quotes.

Third, never ever call `bash` when you need to call *a shell* unless you really mean you *need* to have a [bashism](https://www.google.com/search?q=bashism) in the script you're passing to the shell. In all other 99.9% cases you should call `/bin/sh` instead which is the standard path to a standard shell which is guaranteed to implement POSIX shell semantics for the scripts it runs. The reason for this is that certain systems (notably, Debian and at least some its derivatives) have `/bin/sh` linked to another shell (in Debian, it's `dash`), which lacks interactive features of `bash` but in exchange it starts up and runs its scripts faster.